# Send null terminated string as byte array to WriteProcessMemory() via P/Invoke

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

My P/Invoke `WriteProcessMemory` method currently looks like this:

```
        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        [return : MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(
            IntPtr hProcess,
            IntPtr baseAddress,
            byte[] bufferToWrite,
            uint numBytesToWrite,
            out IntPtr numBytesWritten
            );
```

I need to send a string to the `bufferToWrite` parameter, but it takes a `byte[]` so I'm converting it to a `byte[]` before passing it in.

My issue is that as .NET strings aren't null terminated, it won't write a terminating null to the remote memory. If I was doing this in unmanaged code I'd allocate the length of the string + terminating null, and put all that in the allocated memory since the "string" I'm reading includes the null. But the managed string doesn't include it.

Maybe I could allocate a buffer large enough to include a terminating null, then do another call to `WriteProcessMemory` to write the null; or I could create a `byte[]` large enough to hold the string + null, write both to the array, and pass it in like that.

But is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare an overload like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
[return : MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(
    IntPtr hProcess,
    IntPtr baseAddress,
    string bufferToWrite,
    uint numBytesToWrite,
    out uint numBytesWritten
);
```

That way you force the marshaller to null terminate the string.

You could pass the data as `IntPtr` and use `Marshal.StringToPtrAnsi`. But then you'd need to manage the memory.

If the text is Unicode, use the `CharSet.Unicode` option.

Comment: If I do it like that, should `numBytesToWrite` take into account the bytes for the terminating null, even though that many bytes won't currently exist in the clr string?

Comment: The marshaller will marshal `string` as a pointer to a null-terminated array of character. You can, and should, account for the null terminator in numBytesToWrite

Comment: Great, this is exactly the sort of solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can also allocate the string plus a null terminator. E.g. if you'd want to write the string

```
string szToWrite = "This is what I want to write";
```

I'd have it converted to a `byte[]` by e.g. using ASCII conversion

```
byte[] aBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(szToWrite);
```

Then just have it joined with an extra null-byte.

```
aBytes = aBytes.Concat(new byte[] { 0x00 }).ToArray();
```

If you want, create your own function `WriteProcessMemoryString`, have it accept a `string` instead of an `byte[]` and use the same concept as above. Also note that you might want to have a different encoding than ASCII, e.g. UTF7/UTF8, or whatever stuff you need natively (e.g. wide-character strings).

Comment: Yeah that's basically one of the options I'd considered, I was just hoping for something with a little less faff than having to manually append a null. I suppose as you say I could create a function and let it take care of the string conversion + append the null. I'll just wait a bit to see if anyone else has any more ideas...